# Understanding typical use of Zorn's lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, axiom-of-choice

I am taking a ring theory class (the class is online...), and we just proved that every ring has a maximal ideal. Anyone who is familiar with the proof knows that in order to prove it, we have to use Zorn's lemma. Basically proofs that are using Zorn's lemma have the same "plan" of the proof, for example, that is the proof:

Suppose $R$ is a ring (with unit) and $I \triangleleft R$ is a proper ideal.
Let $S$ be the set that contains $I$ and all the ideals $K$ such that $I\subseteq K$.
Let $C$ be a chain, and now we can define $J=\bigcup_{I\in C}I$. It is easy to verify that $J$ is an ideal, and because each ideal in the union doesn't include $1_R$ , $J$ doesn't include $1_R$ as well, thus, $J$ is also a proper ideal ($J\in S$). So we have found an upper bound for each chain, and now, by **Zorn's lemma** we can conclude that $S$ has a maximal element, (which is a maximal ideal).

So, my question is: why do we need Zorn's lemma? why isn't the union a maximal element? also, in general, if we find an upper bound like that in other proofs similar to this one ('every vector space has a basis' for example) , why it  is not a maximal element?

Comment: *why isn't the union a maximal element?* You have no reason to believe the union is even an element of the poset in question: the poset of *proper* ideals.  It could very well be *the entire ring.* Zorn's lemma lets you conclude it is proper. That shows the union is an upper bound *in* the poset (not a maximal element.) Zorn's lemma asserts that when we are in this situation, you know maximal elements of the poset exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The union is simply an upper bound of the chain. What if the chain had one element, say $\{I\}$? The union of this chain is just $I$. So why is $I$ a maximal element now?

The only condition on the chain itself which ensures that its upper bound is a maximal element is to require that it is maximal. But now you're working around yourself: requiring that every partial order has a maximal chain is equivalent to Zorn's lemma.

What Zorn's lemma ensures is that by checking a local condition (i.e. that chains have upper bounds), we can derive a global property of the partial order (i.e. the existence of a maximal element).

---

If you want to understand better the use of Zorn's lemma, I suggest thinking about the Teichmüller–Tukey lemma instead:

We say that a family of sets $\scr F$ has *finite character* if $A\in\scr F$ if and only if every finite $A_0\subseteq A$ is also in $\scr F$.

> (Teichmüller–Tukey) Let $\scr F$ be a family of sets with finite character. Then $\scr F$ has a maximal element under $\subseteq$.

To see why this is "the usual use of Zorn's lemma", note that the standard appeal to Zorn's lemma is in the case where a certain property is of finite character. For example, in the case vector space bases, being linearly independent is a property that has finite character: if a set is not linearly independent, there is a finite subset witnessing that.

The only reason to use Zorn's lemma is that sometimes it's slightly simpler. Like in the case that you want to extend an ideal to a maximal ideal, or even extend a given linearly independent set to a basis. But the idea stays the same, we use the finite character of our property.

Comment: I think i got it but just to make it clear, there is no assumption that the cain will be infinite, I mean lets take for exmaple the set $\{\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$ so a chain can also be only the singelton $\{a\}$ , and there could be another chain $\{a\}\subseteq {\{a,b\}}$ that contains the first chain? so what the lemma states for in that case is that because every chain here is bounded, there is a maximal element - in this example $\{a,b\}$.

Comment: Yes, there is no assumption on the chain. At all. Although in your example the chain would be $\{\{a\}\}$ and the large chain would be $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$.

Comment: can you also say that for each chain, the union is the **maximum** of the specific chain right?

Comment: Yes. In the "usual case" the union of a chain is in fact its least upper bound, and in the case the chain has a maximum (e.g., if the chain is finite), it will be just that.